# How is context switched back when execv() fails?

Tags: c, exec

So `execv` replaces the calling process image with a new process image, but when it fails, how is old process image recovered? For example, the following code will produce error message:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

  char * ls_args[2] = {"nonsense", NULL} ;
  execv( ls_args[0], ls_args);

  //only get here if exec failed                                                                                                                                             
  perror("execve failed");
  return 2;                                                                                                                             
}
```

I know that kernel scheduler manages a group of contexts of concurrent processes, but `execv()` overwrites old context... is old process image backed up somewhere? The materials I'm learning haven't mentioned about it, nor googling helps, thanks!

Comment: I haven't read anything specific in the man pages about that, but I presume that `execv` only replaces the process when it succeeds. With what should `execv` replace the current process when it fails?

Comment: `execv` is a library function call, so if it cannot launch the new process, the old one has not yet been terminated.

Comment: Hi @Pablo since `execv` doesn't create a new process, it needs the current process to load new context, otherwise it can't run in the first place, let alone succeeding or not?

Comment: If execv fails it does not "overwrites old context". The process can just continue where it left off - the next line of code after the execv call.